# Using Firebase .net Admin Sdk with a Proxy Server to send push notifications

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, proxy, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send PushNotifications from my server to mobile devices with Firebase Cloud Messaging.
The server is behind a proxy and for some reason i cannot get through that proxy.

(When testing locally without proxy everything works as expected)

I am getting the following error:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"Server response does not contain a JSON
object. Status code is: ProxyAuthenticationRequired", Description:"", Uri:""
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.FromHttpResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, Clock clock, ILogger logger)
```

Full Stack-Trace:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"Server response does not contain a JSON object. Status code is: ProxyAuthenticationRequired", Description:"", Uri:""
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.FromHttpResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, IClock clock, ILogger logger)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.ExecuteAsync(TokenRequest request, HttpClient httpClient, String tokenServerUrl, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IClock clock, ILogger logger)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.RefreshTokenAsync()
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.<>c.<GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync>b__10_0(Task`1 task)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.TokenRefreshManager.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.GetAccessTokenWithHeadersForRequestAsync(String authUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceCredential.InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.CredentialInterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndReadAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.SendAndDeserializeAsync[TResult](HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessagingClient.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message, Boolean dryRun)
at FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.SendAsync(Message message)
at Proxy_Test.Program.SendTestMessage() in C:[...]\Program.cs:line 23
```

This is the minimum code, to recreate the issue.
Basically i am creating an FirebaseApp with the credentials and the proxy settings. Then i send a test-message a to specific device. When i comment the line 7 where i am setting the `HttpClientFactory` it works locally.

Using the `HttpClientHandler` to make a normal Http-Get request results in a success so the credentials and proxy adress are correct.
I also successfully tried to reach googleapis.com manually through the proxy so the proxy is not blocking the address in some kind but maybe i am missing something.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppOptions options = new AppOptions(){
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path-to-file-with-key"),
            HttpClientFactory = new ProxyAwareHttpClientFactory()
        };
        FirebaseApp.Create(options);
        SendTestMessage();
    }
    public static async Task SendTestMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            string token = "device-token";
            var notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
            {
                Token = token,
                Notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification()
                {Title = "Notification Title",Body = "Notification Body",}
            };
            var response = await FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(notification);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ProxyAwareHttpClientFactory : HttpClientFactory
{
    protected override HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
    {
        ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential("proxy-user", "proxy-pw");
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(Address: "proxy-uri", BypassOnLocal: false, BypassList: null, Credentials: credentials),
            UseProxy = true,
        };
        return httpClientHandler;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

**Update:**
I set up a local proxy server with squid to further test this. I am only getting these errors in the production environment. So i am guessing it is a problem with the proxy config. But as i mentioned, when i try to access the googleapis.com services manually via the proxy everything seems to work just fine. I really dont know what i am missing here...

Comment: "fun" fact: this worked in my local environment because i did not limit my network to only allow traffic through that squid proxy. So the first auth call went through normal network and the send itself took the proxy route... 
I only found that out, because i traced the pakets with wireshark and found the auth headders were missing with the first packets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. I case anyone having the same trouble ill post the answer:

The Problem was, that FirebaseApp has two seperate network request. First is to Authenticate. Second to send the Message to the service.

Handing over the ProxyData just in the `AppOptions` in `HttpClientFactory` is not enough, but you also have to provide the proxy settings in the `credential`  part.
Therefore you can create the credential object like this:

```cs
var factory = new ProxyAwareHttpClientFactory();
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path-to-file-with-key");
credential = credential.CreateWithHttpClientFactory(factory);

AppOptions proxyOptions = new AppOptions(){
    Credential = credential,
    HttpClientFactory = factory
};

FirebaseApp.Create(proxyOptions);
```

be aware this feature was introduced in Google.Apis.Auth v 1.52.0 ([see this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1547https://))
FirebaseAdmin 2.3.0 (latest Nuget version) however only requries Google.Apis.Auth v 1.49.0  So in my case i needed to manually update Google.Apis & Google.Apis.Auth to v 1.60.0 (current version) to be able to use this method.

This issue took me my 4 day. Hope anyone who stumbles accros this can save some time and energy.